# Remove double quotes from iterator when using csv writer

Tags: python, csv, double-quotes

I want to create a csv from an existing csv, by splitting its rows.

Input csv:

```
A,R,T,11,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25
```

Output csv:

```
A,R,T,11,12,13,14,15
A,R,T,21,22,23,24,25
```

So far my code looks like:

```
def update_csv(name):
    #load csv file
    file_ = open(name, 'rb')
    #init first values
    current_a = ""
    current_r = ""
    current_first_time = ""
    file_content = csv.reader(file_)
    #LOOP
    for row in file_content:
        current_a = row[0]
        current_r = row[1]
        current_first_time = row[2]
        i = 2 
        #Write row to new csv
        with open("updated_"+name, 'wb') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow((current_a,
                             current_r,
                             current_first_time,
                             ",".join((row[x] for x in range(i+1,i+5)))
                             ))
            #do only one row, for debug purposes
            return
```

But the row contains double quotes that I can't get rid of:

```
A002,R051,02-00-00,"05-21-11,00:00:00,REGULAR,003169391"
```

I've tried to use `writer = csv.writer(f,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)` and got a `_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set`.

What is the correct approach to delete those quotes?

Comment: did you try converting row[x] to string. i.e str(row[x])?

Comment: You haven't specified the escapchar. as specified in the link https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE, you need to set the escapechar to use QUOTE_NONE

Comment: @user2109788 : yep with no success:
A002,R051,02-00-00,<generator object <genexpr> at 0x373ca50>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could simplify the logic to split each row into two using something along these lines:

```
def update_csv(name):
    with open(name, 'rb') as file_:
        with open("updated_"+name, 'wb') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            # read one row from input csv
            for row in csv.reader(file_):
                # write 2 rows to new csv
                writer.writerow(row[:8])
                writer.writerow(row[:3] + row[8:])
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider also up-voting my answer if you think it's worthy. Thanks.

Comment: need 15 rep. for that...will upvote when I meet the quota. sorry

Comment: Oh, yeah, that...no problem. BTW I updated my answer slightly to be more complete.

Answer (score 0):

`writer.writerow` is expecting an iterable such that it can write each item within the iterable as one item, separate by the appropriate delimiter, into the file. So:

```
writer.writerow([1, 2, 3])
```

would write `"1,2,3\n"` to the file.

Your call provides it with an iterable, one of whose items is a string that *already contains the delimiter*. It therefore needs some way to either escape the delimiter or a way to quote out that item. For example,

```
write.writerow([1, '2,3'])
```

Doesn't just give `"1,2,3\n"`, but e.g. `'1,"2,3"\n'` - the string counts as *one item* in the output.

Therefore if you want to not have quotes in the output, you need to provide an escape character (e.g. `'/'`) to mark the delimiters that shouldn't be counted as such (giving something like `"1,2/,3\n"`).

However, I think what you actually want to do is include all of those elements as separate items. **Don't** `",".join(...)` them yourself, try:

```
writer.writerow((current_a, current_r,
                 current_first_time, *row[i+2:i+5]))
```

to provide the relevant items from `row` as separate items in the tuple.

Comment: Nice explanation, i'll keep that in my favs.